# Recurrence Equation and sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$a_n $ is a sequence defined this way:
[image]

and we define: [image]

need to prove that this happens:
[image]

i got exam soon and a lot of simmilar questions but i have no idea where to start

Comment: $y_{n+1}=a_{2n+2}=\frac13a_{2n+1}=\frac13(a_{2n}+\frac13)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given information, $y_{n+1}=a_{2n+2}=\dfrac13a_{2n+1}=\dfrac13\left(a_{2n}+\dfrac13\right)=\dfrac13y_n+\dfrac19$.

Now can you show that $x_{n+1}=\dfrac13x_n+\dfrac13$?

Comment: thank you i got a bit of grasp because of your solution but not sure i did right $x_{n+1}=a_{2(n+1)-1}=a_{2n+1}=a_{2n-1}* \dfrac13+1=\dfrac13x_{n} $

Comment: $x_{n+1}=a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}+\dfrac13=\dfrac13a_{2n-1}+\dfrac13=\dfrac13x_n+\dfrac13$

Answer (score 1):

From the concept of GP, note that $T_{n+1}=r T_n \implies T_n=r^n K.$
Here we have

$$3X_{n+1}=X_n+1.$$ Let $X_n=F_n+C$, then $$3F_{n+1}+3C=F_N+C+1/3, \implies 3F_{n+1}=F_n, C=1/6 \implies F_n =3^{-n} D$$
So we have $$X_n=3^{-n}D+1/6,$$ $X_1=3$ gives $D=17/2$, so we have
$$X_n=\frac{17}{2} 3^{-n}+\frac{1}{6}.$$

Next, $$Y_{n+1}=Y_n/3+1/9$$ LEt $Y_n=G_N+P$, then
$$ G_{n+1}+P=\frac{1}{3}G_n+\frac{P}{3}+\frac{1}{9} \implies G_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3} G_n, P=1/4$$
$$\implies Y_n= 3^{-n} Q+\frac{1}{4}$$
$$Y_1=a_2=1 \implies Q=
9/4 \implies Y_n=\frac{3^{2-n}+1}{4}$$